# Definition of function proof

Tags: functions, proof-verification

My goal is to show that the following expression does not satisfy the definition of a function.

f : $R$ $\rightarrow$ $Z$ , *f ( x ) = x*

Solution : If *f* is indeed a function, then *f* can be expressed as a set *f*, composed of members of the ordered pair...

$\{$ ( a , b ) | a ∈ $R$, b ∈ $Z$ , b = a $\}$

This set is not defined. Whole numbers are not always equal to real numbers. Therefore *f* is not a function. Is this correct? More over, can we always examine the definition of a function in this fashion.

Comment: It is correct that $f$ is not well-defined since $f(x):=x\not\in\Bbb Z$ whenever $x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer functions are identified with their graphs.

Let me start with this:

If $C$ is a set then: $$\mathsf{Dom}(C):=\{a\mid \exists b\;(a,b)\in C\}$$
and:$$\mathsf{Ran}(C):=\{b\mid \exists a\;(a,b)\in C\}$$

$f$ is a function if it is a set of ordered pairs and moreover for every $a\in\mathsf{Dom}(f)$ there is not more than one $b\in\mathsf{Ran}(f)$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.

In that case we can speak of a function $f:A\to B$ where $A=\mathsf{Dom}(f)$ and $\mathsf{Ran}(f)\subseteq B$.

Doing so we say that $B$ is the codomain of $f$.

---

Now your question.

About $f:=\{(a,b)\mid a\in\mathbb R,b\in\mathbb Z,b=a\}$ you are saying: "This set is not defined."

That however is a *wrong* statement.

Surely the set is defined, and it can be recognized as the set $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$.

But we evidently have $\mathsf{Dom}(f)=\mathbb Z$ so that $\mathsf{Dom}(f)\neq\mathbb R$.

That is enough to conclude that $f$ cannot be looked at as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$.